# UICollectionViewCell AutoLayout dynamic height based on UILabel

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I am using auto layout and size classes with UICollectionViewCell. So the idea is to make an UI similar with Instagram.

The problem is that i can't fully understand how to add a proper autolayout because it seems add missing constraint didn't do the things magically.

[image]

when I add constraints, even there is no warning, it always shows "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint" on target output. The goal is to make the profile cell dynamic based on iphone types, and dynamic height based on the bioLabel. For now I make it static which is very wrong, because when I use this method

```
systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize
```

it always return zero, and I guess its because of the misplace autolayout constraints. Can you advice me how can I calculate cell's size based on it's constraints? I had created the project in github, anyhelp would be much appreciated!

[CollectionViewAutoLayout](https://github.com/xeravim/CollectionViewAutoLayout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded your code and found the issue. See, you can solve your issue simply by replacing this line of codes in your collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath method.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        CGFloat height = [self findHeightForText:@"Description about yourself, who you are and what impact did you do to the environment. did you do to the environment. Description about yourself, who you are and what impact did you do to the environment. did you do to the environment. who you are and what impact did you do to the environment. did you do to the environment. who you are and what impact did you do to the environment. did you do to the environment." havingMaximumWidth:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width andFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]];
        return CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 150 + height);
    }
    else {
        return CGSizeMake((([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 2.0) / 3.0), (([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 4.0) / 3.0));
    }
}
```

Add this method to calculate height dynamically.

```
 #pragma mark - Height Calculation Method
- (CGFloat)findHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingMaximumWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font {
    CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
    if (text) {
        //iOS 7
        CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
        size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 1);
    }
    return size.height;
}
```

Replace it once and test in all devices and let me know...  Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you man! It solves the issue, but how about the autolayout? can you give advice how to make it right? So i can understand how the autolayout works.. but I will accept your answer now.